# How to loop over paths in python?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and programming.

I want to loop over these path:

```
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/00/  
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/01/    
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/02/

/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/00/   
/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/01/      
/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/02/     

/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/00/   
/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/01/      
/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/02/
```

After evtgen I have one stream start from 00 and and sub stream continues to 10 from 00.
Then another stream starts at 01 and again sub stream starts from 00 to 10.

I want to loop over all those path to submit jobs in python.

Could you please provide me a skeleton code for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards

Comment: Put a for loop inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print('/group/e000055/evtgen/0%s/all/0%s/' % (i,j))
```

**Output**:

```
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/00/
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/01/
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/02/
...
...
/group/e000055/evtgen/09/all/08/
/group/e000055/evtgen/09/all/09/
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating these names, or do these paths already exist and you want to get a list of them?  If the latter, the `glob` function is what you want.

```
>>> import glob
>>> print(glob.glob("/usr/lib/*/*.so"))
['/usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so', '/usr/lib/tc/q_atm.so', '/usr/lib/tc/m_ipt.so', '/usr/lib/tc/m_xt.so', '/usr/lib/man-db/libmandb.so', '/usr/lib/man-db/libman.so', '/usr/lib/man-db/libman-2.9.1.so', '/usr/lib/man-db/libmandb-2.9.1.so',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = '/group/e000055/evtgen/0'

for i in range(3):
    path1 = path + str(i) + '/all/0'
    for j in range(1, 4):
        print(path1 + str(j) + '/')

output:

/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/01/
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/02/
/group/e000055/evtgen/00/all/03/
/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/01/
/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/02/
/group/e000055/evtgen/01/all/03/
/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/01/
/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/02/
/group/e000055/evtgen/02/all/03/
```